# How to check if a files exists in a specific directory in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, file, scripting, terminal

This is what I have been trying and it is unsuccessful. If I wanted to check if a file exists in the ~/.example directory

```
FILE=$1
if [ -e $FILE ~/.example ]; then
      echo "File exists"
else
      echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Write the path you want to check in the test. Do you want to check for a `$FILE ~/.example` file?

Comment: How we can check *.txt files available in /home/tmp  directory  ??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `$FILE` to concatenate with the directory to make the full path as below.

```
FILE="$1"
if [ -e ~/.myexample/"$FILE" ]; then
    echo "File exists"
else
    echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
FILE=$1
if [[ -e ~/.example/$FILE && ! -L ~/example/$FILE ]]; then
      echo "File exists and not a symbolic link"
else
      echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

It will tell you if `$FILE` exists in the `.example` directory ignoring symbolic links.

You can use this one too:

```
[[ -e ~/.example/$FILE && ! -L ~/example/$FILE ]] && echo "Exists" || echo "Doesn't Exist"
```

Comment: This specifically tests whether it's a plain file. The `-e` in the OP's question tests for anything with the right name, e.g. it could be a directory.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, @Kenster, I took file as plain file, even though OP used -e. Maybe he is meaning both file and folder by file in the context.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party here but a simple solution is to use -f

```
if [[ ! -f $FILE]]
then
  echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

A few more examples [here](https://devconnected.com/how-to-check-if-file-or-directory-exists-in-bash/) if you're curious